# File retrieving in MongoDB using C++ Drivers

Tags: c++, mongodb

I am doing one project to make a database application in which i need to store some files in the database and later i need to retrieve those files back to the local system. I am using C++ drivers of the mongoDB..Storing the files on the server is working perfectly and when i am trying to retrieve it back only text files are received as it is but when i am doing it with images, .pdf files or other files format the file is corrupt.Can anyone tell me how i can save the files on local system without any corruption. Thanks

Code:

```
  std::fstream out;  
  const char* gridfilename="Penguins.jpg";
  const char* filename="Temp.jpg";

   out.open(filename, ios::out);   
   DBClientConnection c;  
   c.connect("localhost");   
   cout << "connected ok" <<endl;  
   GridFS gfs = GridFS(c, "Test", "DB");  
   GridFile gf = gfs.findFile(gridfilename);  

   if (true != gf.exists()) {  
      cerr << "There is no file like " << gridfilename << endl;   
   }  
   gf.write(out);     
   out.close();
```

Comment: Do you have some code to show us what's going on?

Comment: Please have a look at the question again.